# I am reading CSV files using OpenCSV in java,

Tags: java, opencsv

In my csv file i have some paths,, and open Csv is reading path without"\",, for example: `C:\abc\ab.txt`  is readed as `C:abcab.txt`. I want to read the as it is without any change ??

Comment: 1. read the line in a String, 2. pass the `\` in 3. use it.

Comment: I have used OPENCSV apis in built functions, CSVReader class,

Comment: that is the problem if i read csv file as a file then it just read half line,,what i need ,is to read the complete entry in 1 go

Answer (score 2):

For OpenCSV, '\' is default escape character. You can change default escape character:

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(
        new FileReader("E:\\download\\sample.csv"),
        CSVParser.DEFAULT_SEPARATOR,
        CSVParser.DEFAULT_QUOTE_CHARACTER,
        '#');
```

By the way, you can try [jCSV](https://code.google.com/p/jcsv/).

Comment: In Java, read string from a file, '\' won't be treated as escape character. It is an escape character in Java code.