# How to display absolute path in excel using apache poi in java

Tags: java, apache-poi

My csv file contains absolute path of a folder 
D:\compare\5.0.60,
D:\compare\5.0.60,
When i am trying to export these data to excel using apache poi output in excel coming like this D:compare5.0.60

Below is the code to export data from csv to excel

```
public void cvstoexcel()
{
     Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
        CreationHelper helper = wb.getCreationHelper();
        Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("Compare");

        CSVReader reader;
        String[] line;
        int r = 0;
        setWorkbookDefaultFontToBold(wb);
        try {
            reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("D:\myfile.csv"));
            while ((line = reader.readNext()) != null) {
                Row row = sheet.createRow((short) r++);
                for (int i = 0; i < line.length; i++)


                        row.createCell(i).setCellValue(helper.createRichTextString(line[i]));

            }
        }

         catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        // Write the output to a file
        FileOutputStream fileOut;
        try {
            parentFolder = yourFile.getParent();
            fileOut = new FileOutputStream(parentFolder+File.separator+"DCompare.xls");
               wb.write(fileOut);
                fileOut.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}
```

but i need output just like cvs file D:\compare\5.0.60 Please help

Comment: try to escape \ with \\

Comment: Daniel,how to add grammatically \ ?

Comment: I got the answer from this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15267782/i-am-reading-csv-files-using-opencsv-in-java